# How to secure an AWS Lambda function?

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, serverless-architecture

I have a simple Lambda function which sends emails through SES. I can call it using a POST request with the required data and it will send an email. My question is, what are the methods I can use to secure this function? Currently, anyone can call that endpoint and execute the function with any data.

Comment: You cannot secure client-side code, unless one considers obfuscation a security measure. Any basic contact form is vulnerable to being spammed, I guess.

Comment: @ChrisG `aws-lambda` is a server side technology

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to set an **authorizer** for your API Gateway. This [tutorial](http://serverless-stack.com/) is a great start point.

In summary, you need to:

1. [Create a Cognito User Pool](http://serverless-stack.com/chapters/create-a-cognito-user-pool.html)
2. [Create a Cognito Identity Pool that uses this User Pool](http://serverless-stack.com/chapters/create-a-cognito-identity-pool.html)
3. [Make the client to log in and retrieve Cognito credentials](http://serverless-stack.com/chapters/login-with-aws-cognito.html)
4. [Make the client to send authorization headers for all requests](http://serverless-stack.com/chapters/call-the-create-api.html)
5. [Set an authorizer in your Lamba function](http://serverless-stack.com/chapters/add-a-create-note-api.html)

Your **serverless.yml** will look like this with the **authorizer** configuration:

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: hello
          method: post
          authorizer:
            arn: YOUR_USER_POOL_ARN
```

<sup>You don't need to be restricted to a Cognito authorizer. You can use configure an authorizer for Google+, Facebook, etc.</sup>

This setting means that the Lamba function will be triggered only by authenticated users and you can identify what is the User ID by inspecting the `event` object:

```
event.requestContext.authorizer.claims.sub
```